# syncfusion datetimepicker I want to set default time

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduler, datetimepicker, syncfusion

hello I'm using the example on this page

[syncfusion example](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Schedule/EditorTemplate#/bootstrap5)

and my problum is that I want to set the default time
like start time : 9:00:00 and end time : 9:30:00

also, client can set time freely...

could you help me T.T ...

and also I want to drag the popup...

I tried

```
        function OnPopupOpen(args) {

        ej.base.addClass([args.element], ['e-draggable']);
```

this code but It doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with this code

```
var titleTextElement = args.element.querySelector('.e-title-text');

var startElement = args.element.querySelector('#START_DATE');
var endElement = args.element.querySelector('#END_DATE');

if (titleTextElement.innerText === 'Edit Event') { 

    new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: new Date(startElement.value), format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }, startElement);
    new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: new Date(endElement.value), format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }, endElement);
}
else{ 
    var initialDate = new Date(startElement.value);
    initialDate.setHours(9, 0, 0);

    new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: initialDate, format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }, startElement);

    initialDate = new Date(endElement.value);
    initialDate.setHours(9, 30, 0);

    new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: initialDate, format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }, endElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the configuration of popup movable. But it can be observed that the popup id is "schedule_dialog_wrapper".
For the 1st question, you can try modify the datepicker part like below

```
if (!startElement.classList.contains('e-datetimepicker')) {
new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: new Date(startElement.value) || new Date(new Date(startElement.value).toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T09:00:00+08:00") }, startElement);
}
var endElement = args.element.querySelector('#EndTime');
if (!endElement.classList.contains('e-datetimepicker')) {
new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: new Date(endElement.value) || new Date(new Date(endElement.value).toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T09:30:00+08:00") }, endElement);
}
```

It will get 9:00-9:30 by default in popup.(change the "+03:00" to your timezone)

Modify explaination:`value: new Date(startElement.value) || xxx` This sentence means if the startelement is not empty choose the front one, or will choose the latter.

Comment: Thank you for leaving a response. However, using this method, although the initial popup displays 9 o'clock correctly, when loading the data, the stored time is not retrieved properly and still shows 9 o'clock.

Comment: @nyny I have modify the answer and it can show correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default time for the new event popup in the editor template by using the below code.

```
 function onPopupOpen(args) {
     if (args.type === 'Editor') {
        if(args.target.classList.contains('e-work-cells')) {
            args.data.StartTime = new Date(args.data.StartTime.setHours(9, 0, 0));
            args.data.EndTime = new Date(args.data.EndTime.setHours(9, 30, 0));
        }
         var startElement = args.element.querySelector('#StartTime');
        if (!startElement.classList.contains('e-datetimepicker')) {
            new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: args.data.StartTime || new Date() }, startElement);
        }
        var endElement = args.element.querySelector('#EndTime');
        if (!endElement.classList.contains('e-datetimepicker')) {
            new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: args.data.EndTime || new Date() }, endElement);
        }
    }
```

Refer to the below shared UG to know about how to drag the popup.

UG: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/common/drag-and-drop#initializing-custom-draggable-element

```
function onPopupOpen(args) {
    var dragElement = args.element;
    var draggable = new ej.base.Draggable(dragElement, { clone: false });}
```